# What method to use to determine the association between multiple choice question in a questionnaire and continuous value outcome

Tags: survey, association-measure, multiple-response

I have data from a questionnaire to determine the level of diabetic foot care knowledge (DFCK) among undergraduate Podiatry students. The DFCK (i.e. outcome) is a score based on the total number of the right answers given by the students for 25 questions related to podiatry.

I want to determine whether there is an association between certain characteristics of the students like age (categorical: < 25 and >=25), gender (M/F), podiatric clinical interest (a list of clinical interests from which the students can choose one or more interests), previous degree (yes/no), previous diabetic foot care experience (yes/no), personal or family history of diabetes (yes/no) and DFCK among undergraduate Podiatry students.

I am doing a Mann-Whitney test for all the variables to determine whether they are associated with DFCK  score but podiatric clinical interest.

As the podiatric clinical interest is a multiple choice question, can someone please help me what method to use to determine whether it is associated with the DFCK score.

my data looks like this.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

A (too?) simple approach would be to transform your podiatric interest variable into multiples dummy variables (one for each interest, i.e. *Diabetes* : yes/no, *Routine* : yes/no, etc.) and perform Mann-Whitney tests as previously. But this won't work if you are more interested in the association between interests.